# Trying to solve this php code getting error

Tags: php

i am trying to print `2` `4` `6` `8` `10` with spaces, but it prints `246810`.

```
for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){
echo $i * 2.' ';
}
```

i am getting error : "This page isn’t working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){
   echo ($i * 2).' ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help.

```
for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){
   echo ($i * 2).' ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo ($i * 2) . ' ';
}
```

the main reason that your code fails is that the `2` is connected with a dot `.`
php interprets the 2 as an invalid type as it expects a digit next to it. e.i. `2.0`

separating the 2 with a space or in the example with a parenthesis (to explicitly tell the logic) will make the code work

Answer (score 2):

***Problem:-***`2.`-> php interprets the 2 as an invalid type because it is expecting a digit next to it something like `2.0`. when you add space that simply tell it to apply multiplication first and then add space with it.

***1.Either add*** a space before `.` like below:-

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){
  echo $i * 2 .' ';
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/856709

***2.Or put*** multiplication into bracket like below:-

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){
  echo ($i * 2).' ';
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/856710